# QGraphicsView drawing huge grid - how to optimize?

Tags: qt4, qgraphicsview

I need to draw a big grid for my app (like 100 rows, 1000 columns). I am using a QGraphicsView with opengl viewport set (doesn't improve performance much).

The app is reasonably responsive, but I'd like to know if I'im doing things right.

Basically I have a GridItem that inherits QGraphicsItem and I have tried two things :

1) The constructor creates thousands of QGraphicsRectItem's passing this (the GridItem) as the (QGraphicsItem*) parent. I have implemented the boundingRect() member correctly (I believe).

2) The constructor creates lots of QGraphicsLineItem's in the same manner.

In both cases, the paint method of GridItem does nothing as the drawing of the child elements is handled automagically by Qt.

Option 1) is about three times faster then option 2). My conclusion is that big lines that extend beyond the viewport are not optimized much and too many objects are redrawn unnecessarily. Do you think this is the correct explanation?

This made me wonder whether I was handling the problem correctly at all. How would you go about drawing a very big grid?

On top of that grid, I have another layer of squares that are clickable, draggable, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

djfm

Comment: I did some further research : speed is correct if I add my items to the scene directly and not to the GridItem. This is not a problem in this case, but it might be useful to be able to have my GridItem as a GraphicsItem in case I want to embed it in a more elaborated scene...